# Show Adwords campaign in contact form

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

What is the best way to fill up a hidden field of our contact form so when an adwords visitor sends us an email we can see the campaign/ad group/keyword?

We use auto tagging, so the final URLs have the ?gclid=XXX appended at the end.

**What we know:**

- From what I know there's no way to ping the GA to decypher the gclid data. So we can't do anything with it when submitting the form.
- If we use both auto tagging and manual tagging (which will create the UTM parameters) we may end up with double reporting inside Google Analytics (although some sources say that GA will ignore manual tags if it sees GCLID)
- ValueTrack is an option, but it shows limited data (you don't get a full picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the additional effort, a possible solution would be to use a tracking template and custom parameters on your campaigns and adgroups.

Your tracking template could look like this:

`{lpurl}?aw_cmp={_campaignname}&aw_adgrp={_adgroupname}&aw_kw={keyword}`

And then you'd set the `_campaignname` and `_adgroupname`custom parameter on all campaigns and ad groups, respectively, to be able to later extract these values from the click URL.

Of course, apart from the cost of the initial setup, this has the disadvantage that your click URLs look a bit ugly and might give unwanted insights into your Adwords account structure.

About having both UTM parameters and auto-tagging, by default the manual parameters will be overridden by the `gclid`.

But there's a setting *"Allow manual tagging (UTM values) to override auto-tagging (GCLID values) for Adwords and DoubleClick Search integration"* in the Analytics property settings that allows you to change this behavior. Obviously, you can't have it both ways.

Comment: thank you, is there a way to indicate inside the template that it should pull the campaignname and adgroupname by itself? I'm reading https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348 and it looks like I can only include campaign and adgroup ids which are numeric

Comment: maybe an alternative would be to specify numeric campaignid and adgroupid and then request the actual names through an API call once the visitor lands on the site? Is that doable?

Comment: Regarding your first question, no unfortunately you can only get numeric IDs from the available ValueTrack parameters.

Comment: Using that and making an API call to get the proper name would be possible, but I think if you use the API anyway, it'd be more efficient to just have a script that sets the names as custom parameters on the campaigns and ad groups.

Comment: ah, interesting.. if only those scripts could be written in PHP.